# Website is crashing on IOS devices

Tags: ios, css, iphone, safari, crash

I am developing a website. But it is constantly crashing on IOS devices on safari. I tried to connect my phone to my computer en check the console log of the page, but because it is crashing, i can not see the logs.

Can someone help me to discover why my website is crashing on safari. And help me to solve the problem.
the website is http://dev.actinc.nl

Comment: You can see which lines are crashing by going to the "Website crashed" page in desktop Safari's Develop menu, open the "Debugger" tab, then click on the blue arrows next to "All Exceptions" and "Assertion Failures", then refresh the page on your iPhone. You can use the debugger to poke around from there

Comment: fix your code errors https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.actinc.nl%2F

Comment: @MichaelHulet when i do that the debugger is also crashing.

Comment: Does it give you an error message? The debugger works as intended on my machine

Comment: @MichaelHulet i dont see the option "Assertion Failures". But i think the error is in my css rather than Javascript. Because when i disable my css it is not crashing. And in the debugger i see only javascript scripts